# Specifying custom error type within the Result type in Swift 5

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a `Result` variable with a custom error type with the builtin Result type in Foundation for Swift 5, but I can't quite get the type system to understand the kind of error I want to throw.

The code below does not compile.

```
import Foundation

enum CustomError: String, Error {
    case somethingBadHappened
}

struct Model {
    let value: Int
}

class Request {
    func execute(number: Int, completion: @escaping (Result<Model, CustomError>) -> Void) {
        let result = Result { () throws -> Model in
            if (number < 20) {
                throw CustomError.somethingBadHappened
            } else {
                return Model(value: number)
            }
        }
        // compiler complains here about: Cannot convert value of type 'Result<Model, Error>' to expected argument type 'Result<Model, CustomError>'
        completion(result)
    }
}

let request = Request()
request.execute(number: 19) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let value): print("Succeded with \(value)")
    case .failure(let error): print("Failed with \(error)")
    }

}
```

Changing the signature of the completion closure to `completion: @escaping (Result<Model, Error>) -> Void` works, but then I am not using the custom error type.

How can I make the type system understand I would like to use the custom error type?

Comment: have you tried to remove the `String` type declaration in your `CustomError` enum?

Comment: The `Result` initializer that takes a block is declared in an extension with a `where Failure == Swift.Error` constraint so you can't use to create a result object with a more custom error type.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/8ec0e39ce83c35f846ff65ffd27263a1f51876ef/stdlib/public/core/Result.swift#L151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create `Result` manually:

```
let result: Result<Model, CustomError>
if (number < 20) {
    result = .failure(.somethingBadHappened)
} else {
    result = .success(Model(value: number))
}
completion(result)
```

Comment: You cannot specify any specific error type with `throws`, thefore you will always get abstract `Error` from the throwing `Result` initializer.

Comment: It is true that `Result.init(catching:)` always returns a `Result<T, Error>`. But you can _transform_ that into a `Result<T, CustomError>` by calling `mapError`, and then you can return that.

Comment: @Sulthan but then you can modify the Result with `mapError` (my new answer demonstrates).

Comment: @matt did you downvote my perfectly legit answer to promote yours?

Comment: @fphilipe Yeah, that was probably the wrong thing to do, sorry. Still, it is wrong to suggest, as your answer now does, that the only way to solve this is to abandon the use of `init(catching:)`. How would you like me to handle this?

Comment: If you are creating the `Result` anyhow, using `init(catching:)` seems like too much ceremony without clear benefit. As I understand it, this makes sense when you're calling some code that might throw. Thus, in this particular case my suggestion is the right approach and hence it shouldn't have a score of -1 :-) That doesn't mean it's not helpful to have other answers that explain how `init(catching:)` works.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't retract my foolish downvote until you edit your answer somehow. — But I don't agree. I find `init(catching:)` extremely beautiful and clear, a much better way to initialize a Result than the `let`-without-an-initialization pattern. However that's still not a reason for downvoting. The reason for downvoting was the blanket claim that you can't use `init(catching:)` as the OP did and still end up with a Result with a custom error type.

Comment: @matt I’ve removed that claim now.

Comment: Great, thanks for doing that. Sorry again for the kerfuffle.

Answer (score 5):

Apologies for giving a second answer, but there needs to be a corrective for fphilipe's answer.

You *can* use `init(catching:)` to form the Result and yet return it as a `Result<Model, CustomError>`. That is what `mapError` is for! Like this:

```
enum CustomError: String, Error {
    case somethingBadHappened
}

struct Model {
    let value: Int
}

class Request {
    func execute(number: Int, completion: @escaping (Result<Model, CustomError>) -> Void) {
        let result = Result { () throws -> Model in
            if (number < 20) {
                throw NSError()
            } else {
                return Model(value: number)
            }
        }.mapError { err in
            return CustomError.somethingBadHappened
        }
        completion(result)
    }
}
```

I have to throw *something* in order to form the initial `Result<Model, Error>`, so I just throw an NSError as a kind of placeholder. But then `mapError` comes along and transforms this into a `Result<Model, CustomError>`. The power of `mapError` is that it changes only what happens in case of failure.

Thus we are able to keep the original form of the code.

Comment: Really nice with mapError, thanks. The main point here for me though is that the compiler won't infer the error type just with `throw`, so one must give the value directly, either on site as per @fphilipe's answer or with mapError, which is arguably more swiftly but more verbose too.

Comment: I’ve summarized the main use patterns here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch05p240ResultTest/ResultTest/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 4):

> Changing the signature of the completion closure to `completion: @escaping (Result<Model, Error>) -> Void` works, but then I am not using the custom error type.

Yes, you are! Change the signature in exactly that way, so that you compile, and then run your code. When we get to this line:

```
case .failure(let error): print("Failed with \(error)")
```

... we print `"Failed with somethingBadHappened"`. That proves that your `CustomError.somethingBadHappened` instance came through just fine.

If the problem is that you want to separate out your CustomError explicitly, then separate it out explicitly as you catch it:

```
case .failure(let error as CustomError): print(error)
default : fatalError("oops, got some other error")
```

Or if you want to winnow it down still further and catch only the `.somethingBadHappened` case, specify that:

```
case .failure(CustomError.somethingBadHappened): print("Something bad happened")
default : fatalError("oops, got some other error")
```

Those examples are artificial, but they demonstrate what they are intended to demonstrate — that your CustomError instance is coming through with full integrity.

Comment: This leaves to the code handling the result to handle the `CustomError` case and other error cases. It would be nice to have a solution where `CustomError` was the only possibility and mapping wasn't necessary. It seems like `init(catching:)` should do the mapping for us.