# Return Result.failure from guard statement in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was exploring `if-case-let` statements that work with `Result` type and do not want to use **switch-case** for this

Consider the following code:

```
import Foundation

enum CustomError: Error {
    case missingData
}

func somethingThatMightReturnError() -> Result<Data,CustomError> {
    .failure(.missingData)
}

func compute() -> Result<String,CustomError> {
    
    let computedValue = somethingThatMightReturnError()
    
    guard case Result.success(let data) = computedValue else {
        /// How to return the CustomError that is inside the computedValue ???
    }
    
    /// Here goes a lot of complex and long code that converts the Data returned as success into String which we need to return
    
    // I have force-unwrap and converted to get rid of the error
    return .success(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
}
```

How do I access the `.failure(error)` inside the **guard's else statement** and return that `error` parameter (of *.failure*) from the function? Is it possible or **switch-case** is the only thing that works here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55784651/specifying-custom-error-type-within-the-result-type-in-swift-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of restricting your approach arbitrarily to use `guard`, I think it is better to use the patterns that Result actually provides. I am very fond of the magical `get`, which turns a Result into a success returned value or a thrown error. One simple approach for your use case, if we adopt `get`, is to return an Error instead of a CustomError, and let the caller deal with it:

```
enum CustomError: Error {
    case missingData
}

func somethingThatMightReturnError() -> Result<Data,CustomError> {
    .failure(.missingData)
}

/// This is where your complex and long conversion code goes
func toString(data: Data) -> String { "dummy result" }

func compute() -> Result<String, Error> {
    do {
        let data = try somethingThatMightReturnError().get()
        return .success(toString(data: data))
    } catch {
        return .failure(error)
    }
}
```

In that formulation, we *do* fail with the error that was thrown, but we don't worry about its type, and we don't need to "look inside" the incoming Result; we just "rethrow" it into the returned Result failure. You have to admit that that is beautifully compact and clear, and we didn't use `switch` (and we didn't use `case let` either).

If you really really insist on returning a Result whose Error is restricted to being a CustomError, you can just bow out (not gracefully) if the incoming Error turns out not to be a CustomError:

```
func compute() -> Result<String, CustomError> {
    do {
        let data = try somethingThatMightReturnError().get()
        return .success(toString(data: data))
    } catch let err as CustomError {
        return .failure(err)
    } catch {
        fatalError("this is not supposed to happen")
    }
}
```

Having said all of that, I would recommend that if at all possible you should abandon Result completely. It is pretty much completely replaced by Combine, and then by `async/await`. It isn't 100% dead, but you are arguably spending your ingenuity in the wrong place. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `computedValue` is not `success` then it's `failure` so simply do

```
guard case Result.success(let data) = computedValue else {
    return computedValue
}
```

If you need to map to different success type the you can just add a dummy `map` inside at the `guard`

```
return computedValue.map { _ in "" }
```

But in this case I would consider a completely different approach that changes the function to be throwing instead

```
func compute() throws -> String  {
    let computedValue = somethingThatMightReturnError()

    let data = try computedValue.get() //This will throw CustomError instead 

    // Here goes a lot of complex and long code that I do not want to put inside a switch-case

    return someString
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked in case the return type(success part of `Result`) of both the methods are same. But I actually needed it for the case where the return type of both the methods are different. I have updated the code sample for the same. Can you suggest what to do in that case?

Comment: @user121095 you can [just map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/map(_:)) your computedValue: all code from `guard` and below can be replaced with `return computedValue.map { data in String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)! }`. Well, if you have complex code inbetween, it also goes into `map`.